# How to use the c++11 chrono functions to get the running cpu frequency

Tags: c++, c++11

How to use the c++11 `chrono` functions to determine a cpu frequency? Runnning OS is Redhat linux

Comment: CPU frequency has nothing to do with clocks, so the answer is, you don't use it. It hardly even make sense nowadays, with frequency scaling and all. You could measure one speed at one point, and later the CPU could speed up or down. What do you need the frequency for?

Comment: just want to print it out ^_^. I saw an example takes numbers of sample of ticks and times, and calculate by their difference to get an average speed.

Comment: Each instruction takes different times to be executed; the compiler will most likely optimize out anything it figures is not doing useful work. Unless you are looping directly in assembly, it's unreliable to estimate anything. By then you might just use the [`CPUID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) instruction (or similar) to read the metadata the CPU has stored about itself from factory. Or use the information the OS already parsed; check out `man cpuid`, it'll probably tell you to check into `/proc/cpuinfo` or `/sys/devices/system/cpu/*`.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you simply can't do that at all.

Comment: The best thing you can do with chrono is `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period`, which gives you the number of ticks per second of the fastest clock. This completely unrelated to the actual CPU frequency though, as it is a compile time constant.

Comment: @ComicSansMS  fastest clock do you mean the max speed of the running cpu?